# why i can't get the right result when I using ContentResolver.update?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'd recently learned Content provider in android.I tried to implement ContentProvider.When I perform updating ,it felt more like  deleting than updating.

```
public void updateBook(Context context){
    String name=edName.getText().toString();
    String isbn=edIsbn.getText().toString();
    String author=edAuthor.getText().toString();
    //String msg="name:"+name+",isbn:"+isbn+",authro"+author;
    String tag="Exercise BookProvider";
    Log.d(tag, "updating a book");
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME, name);
    cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_ISBN, isbn);
    cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_AUTHOR, author);

    ContentResolver cr=context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri=BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.CONTENT_URI;
    Uri updateUri=Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, Integer.toString(4));
    Log.d(tag, "update uri:"+updateUri);
    int count=cr.update(updateUri, cv, null, null);

    Log.d(tag, "updated count:"+count);
}
```

Befor i ran this ,therea was already a book whose id was 4.The update count returned 1.But when i tried to call show_books method ,the book 4 was disappear.It returned all books without book 4.I'll give my full code for my test activity.

```
public class TestBookProvider extends Activity{

EditText edName,edAuthor,edIsbn;
Button addBtn,delBtn,updateBtn,showBtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bookprovider);
    edName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edName);
    edAuthor=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAuthor);
    edIsbn=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edIsbn);

    addBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    delBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.delBtn);
    updateBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);
    showBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.showBtn);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            addBook(TestBookProvider.this);
            //Toast.makeText(TestBookProvider.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    showBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showBooks(TestBookProvider.this);
        }
    });
    delBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            removeBook(TestBookProvider.this);
        }
    });
    updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            updateBook(TestBookProvider.this);
        }
    });
}
public void updateBook(Context context){
    String name=edName.getText().toString();
    String isbn=edIsbn.getText().toString();
    String author=edAuthor.getText().toString();
    //String msg="name:"+name+",isbn:"+isbn+",authro"+author;
    String tag="Exercise BookProvider";
    Log.d(tag, "updating a book");
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME, name);
    cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_ISBN, isbn);
    cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_AUTHOR, author);

    ContentResolver cr=context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri=BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.CONTENT_URI;
    Uri updateUri=Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, Integer.toString(3));
    Log.d(tag, "update uri:"+updateUri);
    int count=cr.update(updateUri, cv, null, null);

    Log.d(tag, "updated count:"+count);
}
public void addBook(Context context){
    String name=edName.getText().toString();
    String isbn=edIsbn.getText().toString();
    String author=edAuthor.getText().toString();
    //String msg="name:"+name+",isbn:"+isbn+",authro"+author;
    String tag="Exercise BookProvider";
    Log.d(tag, "adding a book");
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME, name);
    cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_ISBN, isbn);
    cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_AUTHOR, author);

    ContentResolver cr=context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri=BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.CONTENT_URI;
    Log.d(tag, "book insert uri:"+uri);
    Uri insertedUri=cr.insert(uri, cv);
    Log.d(tag, "inserted uri:"+insertedUri);

}
public void removeBook(Context context){
    String tag="Exercise BookProvider";
    Log.d(tag, "remove a book");
    int i=getCount(context);
    ContentResolver cr=context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri=BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.CONTENT_URI;
    Uri delUri=Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, Integer.toString(i));
    Log.d(tag, "del uri:"+delUri);
    cr.delete(delUri, null, null);
    Log.d(tag, "new count:"+getCount(context));
}
private int getCount(Context context){
    Uri uri=BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.CONTENT_URI;
    Activity a=(Activity)context;
    Cursor c=a.managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
    int numberOfRecords=c.getCount();
    c.close();
    return numberOfRecords;
}
public void showBooks(Context context){
    String tag="Exercise BookProvider";
    Uri uri=BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.CONTENT_URI;
    Activity a=(Activity)context;
    Cursor c=a.managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
    int iname=c.getColumnIndex(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME);
    int iisbn=c.getColumnIndex(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_ISBN);
    int iauthor=c.getColumnIndex(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_AUTHOR);
    Log.d(tag, "name,isbn,author:"+iname+iisbn+iauthor);
    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        String id=c.getString(1);
        String name=c.getString(iname);
        String isbn=c.getString(iisbn);
        String author=c.getString(iauthor);
        StringBuffer buf=new StringBuffer(id);
        buf.append(",").append(name);
        buf.append(",").append(isbn);
        buf.append(",").append(author);
        Log.d(tag, buf.toString());
    }
    int numberOfRecords=c.getCount();
    Log.d(tag, "num of records:"+numberOfRecords);
    c.close();
}
```

}

here is my bookProvider

```
public class BookProvider extends ContentProvider {
private static final String TAG = "BookProvider";
private static HashMap<String, String> sBooksProjectionMap;
static {
    sBooksProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    sBooksProjectionMap.put(BookTableMetaData._ID, BookTableMetaData._ID);
    sBooksProjectionMap.put(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME,
            BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME);
    sBooksProjectionMap.put(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_ISBN,
            BookTableMetaData.BOOK_ISBN);
    sBooksProjectionMap.put(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_AUTHOR,
            BookTableMetaData.BOOK_AUTHOR);
    sBooksProjectionMap.put(BookTableMetaData.CREATED_DATE,
            BookTableMetaData.CREATED_DATE);
    sBooksProjectionMap.put(BookTableMetaData.MODIFIED_DATE,
            BookTableMetaData.MODIFIED_DATE);
}
private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher;
private static final int INCOMING_BOOK_COLLECTION_URI_INDICATOR = 1;
private static final int INCOMING_SINGLE_BOOK_URI_INDICATOR = 2;
static {
    sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(BookProviderMetaData.AUTHORITY, "books",
            INCOMING_BOOK_COLLECTION_URI_INDICATOR);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(BookProviderMetaData.AUTHORITY, "books/#",
            INCOMING_SINGLE_BOOK_URI_INDICATOR);

}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, BookProviderMetaData.DATABASE_NAME, null,
                BookProviderMetaData.DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "inner oncreated called");
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("CREATE TABLE " + BookTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME);
        sql.append("(");
        sql.append(BookTableMetaData._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,");
        sql.append(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME + " TEXT,");
        sql.append(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_ISBN + " TEXT,");
        sql.append(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_AUTHOR + " TEXT,");
        sql.append(BookTableMetaData.CREATED_DATE + " INTEGER,");
        sql.append(BookTableMetaData.MODIFIED_DATE + " INTEGER ");
        sql.append(");");
        db.execSQL(sql.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "inner onupgrade called");
        Log.w(TAG, "upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + " ,which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BookTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

private DatabaseHelper mOpenHelper;

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase db=mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int count;
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case INCOMING_BOOK_COLLECTION_URI_INDICATOR:
        count=db.delete(BookTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
        break;
    case INCOMING_SINGLE_BOOK_URI_INDICATOR:
        String rowId=uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
        count=db.delete(BookTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME, BookTableMetaData._ID+"="+rowId+(!TextUtils.isEmpty(where)? " AND ("+where+")": ""), whereArgs);

        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown uri "+uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case INCOMING_BOOK_COLLECTION_URI_INDICATOR:
        return BookTableMetaData.CONTENT_TYPE;
    case INCOMING_SINGLE_BOOK_URI_INDICATOR:
        return BookTableMetaData.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;

    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown uri " + uri);
    }

}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (sUriMatcher.match(uri) != INCOMING_BOOK_COLLECTION_URI_INDICATOR) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown uri " + uri);
    }
    ContentValues values;
    if (initialValues != null) {
        values = new ContentValues(initialValues);
    } else {
        values = new ContentValues();
    }
    Long now = Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if (!values.containsKey(BookTableMetaData.CREATED_DATE)) {
        values.put(BookTableMetaData.CREATED_DATE, now);
    }
    if (!values.containsKey(BookTableMetaData.MODIFIED_DATE)) {
        values.put(BookTableMetaData.MODIFIED_DATE, now);
    }
    if (!values.containsKey(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME)) {
        throw new SQLException(
                "Failed to insert row because Book Name is Needed " + uri);
    }
    if (!values.containsKey(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_ISBN)) {
        values.put(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_ISBN, "unknown isbn");
    }
    if (!values.containsKey(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_AUTHOR)) {
        values.put(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_AUTHOR, "unknown author");
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long rowId = db.insert(BookTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME,
            BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME, values);
    if (rowId > 0) {
        Uri insertedBookUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                BookTableMetaData.CONTENT_URI, rowId);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertedBookUri,
                null);
        return insertedBookUri;
    }
    throw new SQLException("failed to insert row into " + uri);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "main onCreate called");
    mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case INCOMING_BOOK_COLLECTION_URI_INDICATOR:
        qb.setTables(BookTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME);
        qb.setProjectionMap(sBooksProjectionMap);
        break;
    case INCOMING_SINGLE_BOOK_URI_INDICATOR:
        qb.setTables(BookTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME);
        qb.setProjectionMap(sBooksProjectionMap);
        qb.appendWhere(BookTableMetaData._ID + "="
                + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("UNKNOWN URI " + uri);

    }
    String orderBy;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder)) {
        orderBy = BookTableMetaData.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
    } else {
        orderBy = sortOrder;
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null,
            null, orderBy);
    int i = c.getCount();
    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return c;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase db=mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int count;
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case INCOMING_BOOK_COLLECTION_URI_INDICATOR:
        count=db.update(BookTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
        break;
    case INCOMING_SINGLE_BOOK_URI_INDICATOR:
        String rowId=uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
        count=db.delete(BookTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME, BookTableMetaData._ID+"="+rowId+(!TextUtils.isEmpty(where)? " AND ("+where+")": ""), whereArgs);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown uri "+uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}
```

}
here is BookProviderMetaData

```
public class BookProviderMetaData {
public static final String AUTHORITY="com.flowers.provider.BookProvider";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="book.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static final String BOOKS_TABLE_NAME="books";

public BookProviderMetaData(){

}
public static final class BookTableMetaData implements BaseColumns{
    private BookTableMetaData(){

    }
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="books";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI=Uri.parse("content://"+AUTHORITY+"/books");
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.flowers.book";
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.flowers.book";
    public static final String DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER="modified DESC";
    public static final String BOOK_NAME="name";
    public static final String BOOK_ISBN="isbn";
    public static final String BOOK_AUTHOR="author";
    public static final String CREATED_DATE="created";
    public static final String MODIFIED_DATE="modified";
}
```

}

If i miss anyting please don't hesitate to tell me!~

Comment: There is way too less information here. What do you mean it "felt more like deleting than updating"? Please tell us what *happens*, not what you *feel*. What is the outcome of your code being run? What did you expect? It seems you try to update a book with id "4". Was there a book with id "4" before this code was run? What "updated count" is printed to the log? 1? 0? What makes you think something was deleted?
Furthermore, did you implement this book provider yourself, and if so, please post your implementation of the update method.

Comment: my implementation of the update method was shown at BookPrivider.and i re-eidt my question.please help~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update method, for the case INCOMING_SINGLE_BOOK_URI_INDICATOR, you are actually calling SqLiteDatabase.delete, rather than update. This seems pretty weird and resembles the problem you are describing. Did you intend to call update here?

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness.Thanks a lot~!